# AJAX to run nodejs file on client input

Tags: node.js, ajax

I've been fiddling with nodejs and html, and i want to run nodejs child_process when the client click a button.
Of course I can't do that directly in html running on browser, so i figured i should do an ajax request to the server side so it can run another file (that will run a command in terminal to execute python script).

I have a **app.js** reading files and outputing it to browser

I also have a **index.html** containing buttons
and **funcs.js** with the script i want to run after button clicked

how can i make that ajax request ?

Here is my code :

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Lights</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

  </head>
  <body class="text-white bg-dark">
    <center>
    <input type="submit" value="OFF" name="OFF" onclick="turnOff()">
    <input type="submit" value="ON" name="ON" onclick="turnOn()">
    </center>
    
    <div id="texttest"> </div>
    <div id="fil"> </div>
    
    
    
    <script>
    
    function turnOff() {
        
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("texttest").innerHTML = "trying off";
            }
        };
        xhttp.open("GET", "funcOff.js", true);
        xhttp.send();

/*      $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "funcOff.js",
            success: function(response){
                document.getElementById("texttest").innerHTML = "trying off";
            }
        });*/
        
        }
        
    function turnOn() {
    
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "turnOn.py",
            success: function(response){
                document.getElementById("texttest").innerHTML = "trying on";
            }
        });
        
        }

    </script>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
http = require("http"),
path = require("path"),
url = require("url"),
fs = require("fs");
const {exec} = require('child_process');

function sendError(errCode, errString, response)
{
  response.writeHead(errCode, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.write(errString + "\n");
  response.end();
  return;
}

function sendFile(err, file, response)
{
  if(err) return sendError(500, err, response);
  response.writeHead(200);
  response.write(file, "binary");
  response.end();
}

function getFile(exists, response, localpath)
{
  if(!exists) return sendError(404, '404 Not Found', response);
  fs.readFile(localpath, "binary",
   function(err, file){ sendFile(err, file, response);});
}

function getFilename(request, response)
{
  var urlpath = url.parse(request.url).pathname; // following domain or IP and port
  var localpath = path.join(process.cwd(), urlpath); // if we are at root
  fs.exists(localpath, function(result) { getFile(result, response, localpath)});
}

var server = http.createServer(getFilename);
server.listen(1000);
console.log("Server available...");
```

funcOn.js

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');


exec('python3 turnOn.py', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (err) {
    //some err occurred
    console.error(err)
  } else {
   // the *entire* stdout and stderr (buffered)
   console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
   console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
  }
});
```

I first run `node app.js` then i go to `localhost:1000/index.html`.
On the browser i can click button and have response, but the script is not running

thanks for your help

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp

Comment: easy to make a simple request, but i need to run a script taht want to access terminal to execute a python.. I already set up a ajax request calling the js file on button click, but nothing happens

Comment: Could you provide code samples of what you already have?

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: I tried to add "datatype : "script" to the jquery ajax request but this acts a a script from cliend and return error "require not defined"